# How do i get the value element that called a modal show in jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have a jQuery event attached to my boostrap modal on the show event. I also have several "Edit" buttons on my page. I want to know which one of the buttons called the show event, I have tried to achieve this by getting the 'target' on the 'e'

but it returns the modal instead on the button that called the modal show.

```
$('#modAddProduct').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
    console.log(e.target);
});
```

I call the modal show on my update ("Edit") button after attaching an event to it as shown below

```
$("#tblProducts tbody").on("click", "#btnUpdateProduct", function () {

    var element = $(this).closest("tr");
    var id = element.attr("id");
    var productName = element.find("#tdDescription").text();
    var costPrice = element.find("#tdCostPrice").text();
    var salePrice = element.find("#tdSalePrice").text();
    var quantity = element.find("#tdQuantity").text();

    $(".modal-body #txtProductName").val(productName);
    $(".modal-body #txtProductCostPrice").val(costPrice.substring(1));
    $(".modal-body #txtProductSalePrice").val(salePrice.substring(1));
    $(".modal-body #txtProductQuantity").val(quantity);
    $(".modal-body #ddProductCategories").prop("disable", true);
    $(".modal-body #ddProductBrand").prop("disable", true);

    $("#modAddProduct").modal("toggle");
});
```

**The whole purpose of this is to pass an id from the Edit button row to the modal, so i can return it to the server through an ajax call**

Comment: just so you to know that `$('#modAddProduct').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {console.log(e.target); });` will not work if modal trigger button doesn't has data attributes `data-toggle` and `data-target`

Answer (score 0):

```
you can use the function on the edit buttons and pass the id to that function like .. Hope it helps !

<button onclick="open_modal(your_unique_id_here)">Edit</button>
<script>
function open_modal(your_unique_id_here){
    console.log(your_unique_id_here);
    $("#abc").modal("show");
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('#modAddProduct').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
    console.log($(e.relatedTarget).data(‘id’);
});
```

And for each edit button pass the parameter:

```
$("#btnUpdateProduct").on('click',{btnId:'btnId1'},function(obj){
  console(obj.data.btnId);
    $("#modAddProduct").modal("show");
});
```